# How to calculate occurrence depending on months/years

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

My table looks like that:

```
ID | Start      | End
1  | 2010-01-02 | 2010-01-04
1  | 2010-01-22 | 2010-01-24
1  | 2011-01-31 | 2011-02-02
2  | 2012-05-02 | 2012-05-08
3  | 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-03
4  | 2010-09-15 | 2010-09-20
4  | 2010-09-30 | 2010-10-05
```

I'm looking for a way to count the number of occurrences for each ID in a Year per Month.
But what is important, If some record has a Start date in the following month compared to the End date (of course from the same year) then occurrence should be counted for both months [e.g. ID 1 in the 3rd row has a situation like that. So in this situation, the occurrence for this ID should be +1 for January and +1 for February].

So I'd like to have it in this way:

```
Year  | Month | Id | Occurrence
2010  | 01    | 1  | 2
2010  | 09    | 4  | 2
2010  | 10    | 4  | 1
2011  | 01    | 1  | 1
2011  | 02    | 1  | 1
2012  | 05    | 2  | 1
2013  | 01    | 3  | 1
```

I created only this for now...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counts AS
    (SELECT 
    id, 
    YEAR (CAST(Start AS DATE)) AS Year_St,
    MONTH (CAST(Start AS DATE)) AS Month_St,
    YEAR (CAST(End AS DATE)) AS Year_End,
    MONTH (CAST(End AS DATE)) AS Month_End
    FROM source)
```

And I don't know how to move with that further. I'd appreciate your help.
I'm using Spark SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following strategy to achieve this:

**Note:**

1. I have created few intermediate tables. If you wish you can use sub-query or CTE depending on the permissions
2. I have taken care of `2 scenarios` you mentioned (whether to count it as 1 occurrence or 2 occurrence) as you explained

**Query:**

Firstly, creating a table with `flags` to decide whether `start` and `end` date are falling on same year and month (1 means YES, 2 means NO):

```
/* Creating a table with flags whether to count the occurrences once or twice */
CREATE TABLE flagged as 
(
  SELECT *, 
  CASE
      WHEN Year_st = Year_end and Month_st = Month_end then 1
      WHEN Year_st = Year_end and Month_st <> Month_end then 2
      Else 0
  end as flag
  FROM
   (
    SELECT 
     id, 
     YEAR (CAST(Start AS DATE)) AS Year_St,
     MONTH (CAST(Start AS DATE)) AS Month_St,
     YEAR (CAST(End AS DATE)) AS Year_End,
     MONTH (CAST(End AS DATE)) AS Month_End
     FROM source
   ) as calc
)
```

Now the flag in the above table will have 1 if year and month are same for start and end 2 if month differs. You can have more categories of flag if you have more scenarios.

Secondly, counting the occurrences for `flag 1`. As we know `year` and `month` are same for flag 1, we can take either of it. I have taken `start`:

```
/* Counting occurrences only for flag 1 */

CREATE TABLE flg1 as (
SELECT distinct id, year_st, month_st, count(*) as occurrence
FROM flagged
where flag=1
GROUP BY id, year_st, month_st
)
```

Similarly, counting the occurrences for `flag 2`. Since month differs for both the dates, we can `UNION` them before counting to get both the dates in same column:

```
/* Counting occurrences only for flag 2 */

CREATE TABLE flg2 as 
(
 SELECT distinct id, year_dt, month_dt, count(*) as occurrence
 FROM 
  (
  select ID, year_st as year_dt, month_st as month_dt FROM flagged where flag=2
  UNION
  SELECT ID, year_end as year_dt, month_end as month_dt FROM flagged where flag=2
  ) as unioned
 GROUP BY id, year_dt, month_dt
)
```

Finally, we just have to SUM the occurrences from both the flags. Note that we use `UNION ALL` here to combine both the tables. This is very important because we need to count duplicates as well:

```
/* UNIONING both the final tables and summing the occurrences */

SELECT distinct year, month, id, SUM(occurrence) as occurrence
FROM
 (
  SELECT distinct id, year_st as year, month_st as month, occurrence
  FROM flg1
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT distinct id, year_dt as year, month_dt as month, occurrence
  FROM flg2
 ) as fin_unioned

GROUP BY id, year, month
ORDER BY year, month, id, occurrence desc
```

Output of above query will be your expected output. I know this is not an optimized one, yet it works perfect. I will update if I come across optimized strategy. Comment if you have question.

*db<>fiddle* link [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cea7a111448475ed0bd39e39f694c0c2)

Comment: Thanks Arun, based on your comprehensive suggestion I was able to tackle it!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works in Spark SQL.

But if the ranges aren't bigger than 1 month, then just add the extra to the count via a `UNION ALL`.
And the extra are those with the end in a higher month than the start.

```
SELECT YearOcc, MonthOcc, Id
, COUNT(*) as Occurrence
FROM 
(
  SELECT Id
  , YEAR(CAST(Start AS DATE)) as YearOcc
  , MONTH(CAST(Start AS DATE)) as MonthOcc
  FROM source
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT Id
  , YEAR(CAST(End AS DATE)) as YearOcc
  , MONTH(CAST(End AS DATE)) as MonthOcc
  FROM source
  WHERE MONTH(CAST(Start AS DATE)) < MONTH(CAST(End AS DATE))
) q
GROUP BY YearOcc, MonthOcc, Id
ORDER BY YearOcc, MonthOcc, Id
```

> ```
> YearOcc | MonthOcc | Id | Occurrence
> ------: | -------: | -: | ---------:
>    2010 |        1 |  1 |          2
>    2010 |        9 |  4 |          2
>    2010 |       10 |  4 |          1
>    2011 |        1 |  1 |          1
>    2011 |        2 |  1 |          1
>    2012 |        5 |  2 |          1
>    2013 |        1 |  3 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e02b72730d8d49bef61fdfbf2ad6f2b)*